# Why are $W$ and $Z$ bosons called 'intermediate' vector bosons?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, terminology, electroweak, carrier-particles

What does the 'intermediate' part mean?  Somehow, I thought an answer would be easy to come across, but I have yet to find one.

Answer (score 3):

There is not much deep meaning to this statement.
They are called *intermediate* just because they *mediate*
the weak nuclear force between other particles
(like protons, neutrons, electrons, neutrinos).

Quoted from [Wikipedia - W and Z bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons#Relations_to_the_weak_nuclear_force):

> **Relations to the weak nuclear force**
>
> The $W$ and $Z$ bosons are carrier particles
> that mediate the weak nuclear force, much as the photon
> is the carrier particle for the electromagnetic force.
> [image: weak interaction with intermediate boson]
> <sub>The Feynman diagram for beta decay of a neutron into a proton,
> electron, and electron antineutrino via an intermediate $W^−$ boson</sub>

This modern theory of weak interaction is in contrast to the older
(and now obsolete) [Fermi's theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction) which tried to model the weak nuclear force without any intermediate particles.

[image: weak interaction without intermediate boson]

Comment: Doesn't the binding force become the antineutrino? Does the energy in the W just disappear?

Comment: @Miss_Understands No. The mass/energy of the final electron and antineutrino is produced from the mass/energy difference between neutron and proton.
The large mass/energy of the virtual $W$ ($90$ GeV) can only be "borrowed"
from vacuum, and therefore needs to disappear after $10^{-25}$ seconds.